# My perl script doesn't see the txt file

Tags: windows, perl, unc

My Perl program creates the file

```
 10001.ICNTL.20160602.20160603.OPR.GAAP.PROD.PFI.PRE.txt
```

Then in method I have a code:

```
if ( -e $report ) {     
    # we parse the filet here is some code, at the end     
{     
else     
}     
    print "*** Skipping \\NYNAS\NYNDS\VOL\DATA\INVACCT\FUND_RECS_PFI\10001.ICNTL.20160603.PROD.GAAP.PFI\10001.ICNTL.20160602.20160603.OPR.GAAP.PROD.PFI.PRE.TXT        
}
```

I cannot understand why the script doesn't see the file. I've checked it several times letter by letter. Can it be because of the Upper case `TXT`, but in reality it is lower case?

Comment: The upper case TXT is probably a problem.

Comment: No, I just changed it to upper case, the same result, skipping

Comment: Your code won't compile. Please copy and paste your real code if you want useful answers. Please show the part of your code that defines `$report` and writes to the file. Is `$report` that string `\\NYNAS\NYNDS\VOL\DATA\INVACCT\FUND_RECS_PFI\10001.ICNTL.20160603.PROD.GAAP.PFI\10001.ICNTL.20160602.20160603.OPR.GAAP.PROD.PFI.PRE.TXT`?

Comment: Re "*I cannot understand why the script doesn't see the file*", How do you know that it doesn't see the file? Please include `$!` in the error message.

Answer (score 2):

Is your file `10001.ICNTL.20160602.20160603.OPR.GAAP.PROD.PFI.PRE.txt` in directory `\\NYNAS\NYNDS\VOL\DATA\INVACCT\FUND_RECS_PFI`?

At a guess you're not escaping the file path correctly. Even if you use single-quotes, there is no way of representing the two leading backslashes in [*Uniform Naming Convention* (UNC) paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Uniform_Naming_Convention) without escaping at least one of them

Check the output of `print $report, "\n"` to see what you've really written

My preference is to use *four* backslashes at the start of the path string, like this

```
my $report = '\\\\NYNAS\NYNDS\VOL\DATA\INVACCT\FUND_RECS_PFI\10001.ICNTL.20160603.PROD.GAAP.PFI\‌​10001.ICNTL.20160602.20160603.OPR.GAAP.PROD.PFI.PRE.TXT';

print -e $report ? "Found\n" : "Not found\n";
```

And Perl allows you to use *forward* slashes in place of backslashes in a Windows path, so you could write this instead if you prefer, but paths like this aren't valid in other Windows software

```
my $report = '//NYNAS/NYNDS/VOL/DATA/INVACCT/FUND_RECS_PFI/10001.ICNTL.20160603.PROD.GAAP.PFI/‌​10001.ICNTL.20160602.20160603.OPR.GAAP.PROD.PFI.PRE.TXT';
```

Or another alternative is to relocate your current working directory. You cannot `cd` to a UNC path on the Windows command line, but Perl allows you to `chdir` successfully

```
chdir '//NYNAS/NYNDS/VOL/DATA/INVACCT/FUND_RECS_PFI' or die $!;
```

Thereafter all *relative* file paths will be relative to this new working directory on your networked system